# Can you simulate joint capacity of multiple resources in Simmer?

Tags: r, simulation

I'm using the Simmer package in R to perform discrete event simulation, and I need to set up constraints on the joint capacity of multiple resources.

Specifically, I'm simulating a restaurant that serves both dinner and dessert customers. The restaurant can accommodate up to five customers of each type concurrently, but there should be a total limit of seven customers in the restaurant at any given time. How can I implement these constraints effectively using the Simmer package?"

I've read lots of simmer vignettes but haven't found anything that deals with this specific problem!